# Formatting date when using CAST

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, ansi-sql, to-char

I would like to use `CAST` to convert a `DATE` type to a `VARCHAR2` type.

```
DBUSER >SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS VARCHAR2(20)) THE_DATE from DUAL;
THE_DATE
--------------------
09-AUG-17
```

However, I need the VARCHAR2 result to be formatted as 'YYYYMM'. I know that I can achieve this effect by changing the session date format, but I would rather not do that.

```
DBUSER >ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMM';
Session altered.

DBUSER >SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS VARCHAR2(20)) THE_DATE from DUAL;
THE_DATE
--------------------
201708
```

I would like to avoid using Oracle's proprietary TO_CHAR() function. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you explain why you don't want to use `TO_CHAR()`.

Comment: Why are you casting to a string at all - is that something your application layer can/should do?

Comment: Oracle and PostgreSQL use `TO_CHAR`, SQL Server uses `CONVERT`, MySQL uses `DATE_FORMAT` ... what language are you trying to standardise with which uses `CAST` to format dates?

Comment: @alexpoole - For better or worse, tables have dates stored as VARCHAR2. Sometimes only YYYYMM. The application wants the database to filter records where the character YYYYMM is > CURRENT_DATE - 13 MONTHS.

Comment: @MT0 - I am trying to standardize on ANSI SQL to the degree possible and avoid proprietary vendor nonstandard implementations.

Comment: Then use plain DATE values and compare directly.

Comment: I'm not sure it's ever 'for better' *8-) And dates seem to be a particular area of divergence between RDBMSs, so while aiming for ANSI is fine using it exclusively is unlikely to be practical. Anyway, my point was, in this case why can't the application calculate the filter value and supply it as a string? (The only reason I can think of is that the application locale and DB session time zone don't match for some reason.)

Comment: @lit My point was that there is **NO** standard method of handling dates - every RDBMS has their own proprietary method and using `CAST` is not a substitute.

Comment: @MT0 - Almost every RDBMS application needs to handle dates. Perhaps this is something that standards makers should turn their attention toward. This would help users avoid falling into vendor proprietary traps.

Comment: Every RDBMS handles dates - some implement the ANSI standard and some do not (including Oracle - the oracle `DATE` datatype is a concatenation of the ANSI `DATE` and `TIME` datatypes and oracle has no `TIME` datatype). However, I cannot find anything in the [SQL92 ANSI standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) that specifies functions to format a datetime as a string; since there is no standard then we are left with proprietary solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be help you:

```
SELECT extract(year from CURRENT_DATE) || case when extract(month from CURRENT_DATE) <10 THEN '0' || extract(month from CURRENT_DATE) END  THE_DATE from DUAL;
```

Comment: Yes, I know that works. I would like to avoid using Oracle's proprietary TO_CHAR() function.

Comment: I edited my answer. I am sorry I missed your explanation about to_char.

Comment: I agree that this works. I agree that it uses ANSI functions. I was hoping for something a little more compact and easier to type. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not using `CAST` to convert a date to a string - this is using `EXTRACT` to get numeric values and then implicit conversion to a string using the string concatenation operator; all the `CAST` does is convert from a string to a string (of max length 20).

Comment: @MT0 - Agreed. The `CAST` is not even needed.

Comment: @mehmetsahin - If you will remove the `CAST` I will select this as the answer. Although, I am still hoping for something better.

Comment: do you want like this?

Comment: @mehmetsahin - No, I do not actually want it like this, but this appears to be as good as it gets at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to standardize on ANSI SQL to the degree possible and avoid proprietary vendor nonstandard implementations.

There is no function specified in the [ANSI SQL92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) which formats `DATETIME` datatypes as a string.

The simplest solution is to use the functions Oracle provides for that purpose:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( yourdate, 'YYYYMM' ) FROM yourtable;
```

However, you can get the year and month components using the `EXTRACT` function (which is in the ANSI standard):

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ),
       EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate )
FROM   yourtable;
```

Then you need to convert the numbers to a string and concatenate the strings:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ) )
       || TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate ) )
FROM   yourtable
```

but you were trying to avoid `TO_CHAR` so you could do:

```
SELECT CAST( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ) AS VARCHAR2(4) )
       || CAST( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate ) AS VARCHAR2(2) )
FROM   yourtable
```

or, using an implicit cast

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate )
       || EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate )
FROM   yourtable
```

However, if the year is not 4-digits or the month is not 2-digits then you need to pad the values; again, the simple solution is `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ), 'FM0000' )
       || TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate ), 'FM00' )
FROM   yourtable
```

or `LPAD`:

```
SELECT LPAD( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ), 4, '0' )
       || LPAD( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate ), 4, '0' )
FROM   yourtable
```

But neither of those are in the `ANSI` standard so:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ) < 10 THEN '000'
         WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ) < 100 THEN '00'
         WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ) < 1000 THEN '0'
         ELSE NULL
       END
       || EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate )
       || CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate ) < 10 THEN '0'
       END
       || EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate )
FROM   yourtable;
```

And we've managed to transform a single Oracle function into a behemoth of an ANSI compatible expression.

But, Oracle's `DATE` datatype does not comply to the ANSI standard (it is a concatenation of the ANSI `DATE` and `TIME` datatypes) so I'll ask whether it is worth it - especially if you then consider displaying the time component of a date (which `EXTRACT` will not extract unless you first use `CAST` to convert the `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP`).

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( yourdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) FROM yourtable
```

or

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ) < 10 THEN '000'
         WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ) < 100 THEN '00'
         WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate ) < 1000 THEN '0'
         ELSE NULL
       END
       || EXTRACT( YEAR FROM yourdate )
       || CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate ) < 10 THEN '0'
       END
       || EXTRACT( MONTH FROM yourdate )
       || CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM yourdate ) < 10 THEN '0'
       END
       || EXTRACT( DAY FROM yourdate )
       || CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST( yourdate AS TIMESTAMP ) ) < 10 THEN '0'
       END
       || EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST( yourdate AS TIMESTAMP ) )
       || CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM CAST( yourdate AS TIMESTAMP ) ) < 10 THEN '0'
       END
       || EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM CAST( yourdate AS TIMESTAMP ) )
       || CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( SECOND FROM CAST( yourdate AS TIMESTAMP ) ) < 10 THEN '0'
       END
       || EXTRACT( SECOND FROM CAST( yourdate AS TIMESTAMP ) )
FROM   yourtable;
```

**[TL/DR]** Just use `TO_CHAR`